# Folding bike rear derailleur upgrade help

Tags: folding-bicycle

[image]

Hey guys,

I have the Tern Link B7 7 speed folding bike. It has 11-28T casette (you can see it in the picture) and I want to upgrade it to 14-34T one. So I bought the casette but the stock rear derailleur can't accomodate it, not enough clearence (height-wise).

So I decided to upgrade the rear derailleur. After a short research I narrowed my options down to 2 models: Shimano Tourney RD-TX55 and Shimano Tourney RD-TX35.

But upon seeing the picture I attached here, online bike store guy told me they are both incompatible with my bike.

Any ideas why and how can I find a compatible rear derailleur?

Comment: Did online guy say why it they were incompatible?  Could be too long in the cage and the bottom could touch the rim (or be low enough to hit things on the ground)  I'm guessing that the online calculator has some limits with a lot of safety margin.

Comment: As per your previous question 
  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/53822, don't give up the small tooth gears or you'll be spinning out on a decent tailwind.

Comment: Give me a couple hours and will get photos of mine....

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re doing, here. Why didn’t you buy a bike that’s suited to the riding you want to do, instead of buying a bike that isn’t suitable and replacing brand-new components?

Comment: That's a standard vanilla rear derailer.  EXCEPT for the way the cable attaches.  I can't tell if the cable wheel thingie is integral to the derailer, or an add-on that could be moved to a new derailer.  In any event you should be dealing with your local bike shop, as one needs to see the setup "in person" to tell what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Its not uncommon - I have at least one like that.  Saves having a cable stop on the chainstay; being a folding bike it will be one piece of housing all the way from shifter to derailleur.  But there's no reason it can't have a normal-looking loop.

Comment: @Criggie - The arrangement shown keeps the cable close to the frame and eliminates most of the risk of snagging it while folding/unfolding, or of snagging simply because there's less bike to fend off potential snags.

Comment: @DavidRicherby why try to lecture him on what he should and shouldn’t buy? If you can answer the question, great. If not, move on.

Comment: @user2670468 Why try to lecture me on what I should and shouldn't say? If you can answer the question, great. If not, move on.